# While and foreach different behaviour with fetching PDO::FETCH_OBJECT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

While using something like:

```
$db = new PDO(connection_details)
$query = "SELECT * FROM vservers LIMIT 5";
$result = $db->query($query);
```

And then try to get records with while f.e.

```
while ($row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

it returns an array with StdObjects  like this:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'vserverid' => string '898' (length=3)
      public 'templatename' => string 'Debian' (length=14)
      public 'template' => string 'debian-7.0-x86' (length=14)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[4]
      public 'vserverid' => string '792' (length=3)
      public 'templatename' => string 'Ubuntu' (length=33)
      public 'template' => string 'ubuntu-15.04' (length=27)
```

And with `foreach` it returns StdObjects

```
    foreach ($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $key) {
        var_dump($key);
    }

object(stdClass)[3]
  public 'vserverid' => string '898' (length=3)
  public 'templatename' => string 'Debian' (length=6)
  public 'template' => string 'debian' (length=6)


object(stdClass)[4]
  public 'vserverid' => string '792' (length=3)
  public 'templatename' => string 'Ubuntu' (length=6)
  public 'template' => string 'ubuntu' (length=6)
```

Can someone please explain this behaviour? Normally, I would like to return Objects like with `foreach`, but is it a good practice ?

Comment: You should use `fetch` with `while`, not `fetchAll`.

Comment: Both are perfectly good and behave as you want. However, depending on what you want to do with the result afterward, you might want to consider the first one to deal with arrays in php and the second one to send it back to ajax and have formated objects. Arrays being faster than objects in php, and objects faster in javascript. Not much but if your result is huge and going across loop, difference can be significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchAll()` returns all the results as an array, where each element is an object that represents a row from the table.

In your `while` code, the first iteration sets `$row` to the entire result set, and dumps it as a single array. There's only one iteration because the next call to `fetchAll()` returns an empty array, because there's nothing left to fetch.

In your `foreach` code, `fetchAll()` returns the array to `foreach`, which then iterates over it one element at a time, setting `$key` to each object. Then you dump that one object in your body.

Normally when you're using `while` you use `fetch()`, not `fetchAll()`. This code will be equivalent to the `foreach`:

```
while ($key = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    var_dump($key);
}
```

Comment: Yes, just tested :-) Thanks for explanation!
Thanks @Barmar